# Click a button inside <span> using Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am trying to click on download button. The HTML Code for the button is as below:

```
<a class="x-btn toolbar-menu x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-transparent-medium" style="padding: 0px 5px; right: auto; left: 1121px; margin: 0px; top: 0px;" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" id="toolbarbutton-1054" tabindex="-1" data-qtip="<b>Export</b><br/>Export your report into a CSV file." componentid="toolbarbutton-1054">
<span id="toolbarbutton-1054-btnWrap" data-ref="btnWrap" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-transparent-medium ">
<span id="toolbarbutton-1054-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-transparent-medium  x-btn-no-text x-btn-icon x-btn-icon-left x-btn-button-center ">
<span id="toolbarbutton-1054-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-transparent-medium sdc-icon-export " style="">&nbsp;</span>
<span id="toolbarbutton-1054-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-transparent-medium">&nbsp;
</span>
</span>
</span>
</a>
```

I tried this :

```
driver.find_element(By.ID , "toolbarbutton-1054-btnEl").click()
```

Getting an error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

When I try below command it does not give error and element is recognizable. It's just that I cannot click on it.

```
driver.find_element(By.ID , "toolbarbutton-1054-btnEl")
```

Comment: Target the <A> tag... driver.find_element(By.ID , "toolbarbutton-1054").click()

Comment: unselectable="on" might need to target the  a tag prior.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the below code

```
class_element= driver.find_element_by_class('x-btn toolbar-menu x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-transparent-medium')
class_element.click()
```

and also you can use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath here')`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Span does not have a clickable feature.

Please execute the following javascript code using python selenium:

```
document.getElementById('toolbarbutton-1054-btnEl').click();
```

I don't know how to execute javascript code using python selenium but it will work.

I used it with C# Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

In Python it should work with the following code:

```py
s=driver.find_element(By.ID , "toolbarbutton-1054-btnEl")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",s)
```

I used the link below for my reference:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python

Comment: That's because  you have two different accounts